# how to add fade out effect in Div of text in HTML5

Tags: html, css

I have text div i want fadeout effect on this when page loads or when div is loaded i have following html code on which i want to perform this

```
<div class="text_paragraph">
    <p>Bovine Respiratory Disease (BRD) is the leading cause of economic 
       loss in the beef industry. <small>1, 2</small></p>
</div>
```

Comment: I have find some function but the are on clcik event of button but i want when div loads not on click

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with CSS3.  Write like this:

```
.text_paragraph >p{
    -webkit-animation: fadi 5s 1;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadi {
    0%   { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 1; }
}
@-moz-keyframes fadi {
    0%   { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 1; }
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/TPsb7/2/

Comment: which browser you are using & for more you can read this http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/webkit-keyframe-animation-syntax/

Comment: thanks it works for me may i add this code mine and  style tag in head section of the html page

Comment: That depends on what browser you're viewing it in.

Comment: i am appying same this for the other div that is not workign i am editing in your code

Comment: @sandeep its working can you tell me the difference what you did becuase i have more 4 paragphs in whici i have to do same thing in first show place p then *

Comment: @sandeep can you help me out this please

Comment: It's called universal selector http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#universal-selector . which match every element & apply properties on it.

Comment: @thanks sandeep but when apply this on the second page inside same html page using paging it don't work on second may i show you the code

Comment: @sandeep when i come back to this page again there is no fading i am using two pages inside one page in HTML file using paging

Answer (score 1):

Fading an element out is generally not done with pure HTML. You can do it with CSS, however by and large it's done with the help of a library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com) which permits you the luxury of performing complicated animations and effects with minimal code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".text_paragraph").fadeOut();
});
```

The above code will fade out your `div` as soon as the document is finished loading.

Comment: if i want to fadeIn(); just repalce this line

Comment: @DeveloperAli If you want to fade it in, yes. However make sure it's hidden to begin with.

Comment: i have done using css but it works for some div not for all can you help me out in this