# Change opacity of one div WITH transition on hover over another div

Tags: html, css, hover, transition, opacity

I'm trying to change the opacity of a div slowly when hovering over another div.

I can change the opacity of the div when hovering over the other div but the problem is that I dont know how to do slowly with a transition.

My code looks like this:

```css
#my-id:hover ~ #info .hc  {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
}
#info div {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
}

.test-border {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="my-id">Hover here</div>
  <div id="info">
    <div class="hc test-border">Information</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10309689/how-to-add-fade-out-effect-in-div-of-text-in-html5

Comment: @gvee This link is not my question therefore it is not a solution for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the [transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) property on the div that changes:

```
#info div {
    transition:opacity 1s ease;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

The problem here is you may need to remove the `display:none` since this property can't be animated by transition.

```css
#my-id:hover ~ #info .hc  {
    opacity: 1;
}
#info div {
    opacity: 0;
    transition:opacity 1s ease;
}

.test-border {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="my-id">Hover here</div>
  <div id="info">
    <div class="hc test-border">Information</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Removing `display:none` was no problem since it is not visible because of the opacity.
So adding the transition property to `#info div` means that this is the starting point and `#my-id:hover ~ #info .hc`is the end point, right?